# ini4j incorrectly parses .ini files with section name [mm/yyyy]?

Tags: java, ini, ini4j

I am using [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/IniTutorial.java.html) API to parse .ini files, in which the section name is in the format [mm/yyyy], where the / character is causing troubles.

Suppose my test.ini file is as follows:

```
[02/2018]
k=v
```

My Java code snippet is:

```
Ini ini = new Ini(new File("test.ini"));        
Set<String> sectionNames = ini.keySet();  
System.out.println("List of Section Names: " + sectionNames + "\n");
```

I got the following output:

```
List of Section Names: [02, 02/2018]
```

where "02" is mistakenly parsed as a section.

Is this a bug or am I using the API properly?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/IniTutorial.java.html

> Tree model Beyond two level map model, Ini class provides tree model.
>   You can access Sections as tree. It means that section names becomes
>   path names, with a path separator character ('/' and '\' on Wini and
>   Reg).

You should be using the Wini class instead of the Ini class

Comment: I was confused by this statement. There are lots of grammatical errors in the ini4j documentation. Does this mean that only in Ini class, sections names become path names, whereas in Wini class, section names are not path names? What does *W* in Wini stand for?

Comment: From reading the doc I would say no path in Wini.   My guess is W stands for Windows.